# Angular Observable dont show me values in real time

Tags: angular, angular6

I have 2 components (Menu and Header) and one Service. What I want to do is that when they select an item from the menu, the menu sends the text to the service and the service sends it to the header and changes it. I already managed to send it to the service, but I do not know why in the header with the Observable it does not update.

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from'; 
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class passVarHelper{

    currentIndex: string;
    constructor(

    ){
        this.currentIndex = "Title";
    }


    getIndex(): Observable <string> {
        return of(this.currentIndex);
    }

    changeIndex(index:string){
        this.currentIndex = index;
        console.log(this.currentIndex);
    }



}
```

**Header:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { passVarHelper } from 'src/app/helpers/passVar.helper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-headerpage',
  templateUrl: './headerpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./headerpage.component.css'],
  providers: [passVarHelper]
})
export class HeaderpageComponent implements OnInit {
  index:string;
  constructor(private _passVarHelper: passVarHelper) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadIndex();
  }

  loadIndex(){
    this._passVarHelper.getIndex().subscribe(
      response  => {
        if(response){
          console.log(response);
          this.index = response;
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

**Menu:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { passVarHelper } from 'src/app/helpers/passVar.helper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-asidenavbar',
  templateUrl: './asidenavbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asidenavbar.component.css'],
  providers: [passVarHelper]
})
export class AsidenavbarComponent implements OnInit {


constructor(private _passVarHelper: passVarHelper) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  menuClick(){
    var indexMenu = document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML;
    this._passVarHelper.changeIndex(indexMenu);

  }


}
```

**Header HTML**

```
<div class="content-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">{{index}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Volver</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are you subscribing to the response?

Comment: do you get the console log from the header subscription to getIndex?

Comment: SideNote: I'd recommend the use of ngrx or ngxs or some kind of state management tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observable.of` is one time event, as per documentation:

> Creates an Observable that emits some values you specify as arguments, immediately one after the other, and then emits a complete notification.

The last part about *complete notification* is important since once it's done (it's executed for the first time) it emits `complete` event and doesn't emit anymore. What you need to do is use `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` in order to get constant stream of events.

Try something like this:

```
@Injectable()
  export class PassVarHelper {
  currentIndex: string;
  currentIndexObs: BehaviorSubject<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.currentIndex = "Title";
    this.currentIndexObs = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.currentIndex);
  }

  changeIndex(index: string) {
    this.currentIndex = index;
    this.currentIndexObs.next(this.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

Then `loadIndex` method:

```
loadIndex() {
  this._passVarHelper.currentIndexObs.subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.index = response;
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(<any>error);
    }
  );
}
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgvpco) example demonstrating this behavior.

**EDIT**: Ok, I see where the problem is... It is in `providers` array, you cannot provide service in `header` nor `menu` components, you have to provide it in component that is above them (like `app.module` or `app.component`). If you provide services in both of these components you will get different instance of the service and what you want to achieve will not work.

Therefore, provide `passVarHelper` in either one of them (if another is child of the first one) or in `app.module.ts` *providers* array (check the *stackblitz* example I provided, I provided service in `app.module.ts`) and **only** in that one place (in order to get the same instance).

Hmm, Angular has something called *provider scope*. For example, take a look at this definition:

> When you provide the service at the root level, Angular creates a single, shared instance of service and injects into any class that asks for it.

That means that when you provide service at the root level, you will get a single instance of that service wherever you inject it using DI (like when you inject it in constructor).

But, you can also provide services in any other component. By providing a service in the component, you are actually limiting the service only to that component and components inside that component. Essentially, by providing a service in component, you will get a new instance of that service when you inject it in that component (and all its children will have that one instance, unless they themselves provide the service).

So, single instance of the service is used for the component and all its children, but if provided in any child component, that child and all its children will get the new instance.

Hope this makes it a bit more clearer.

Interesting reading material:

- [Official documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#provide-the-heroservice)
- [Provider scope](https://itnext.io/understanding-provider-scope-in-angular-4c2589de5bc)

Comment: great this solve the problem whit the character but the header dont upgrade :c

Comment: Yes, I missed something very obvious, my bad, try this version (also check updated stackblitz)...

Comment: Continue without updating ggrrrr

Comment: Uhh, I think I finally got it... It is because of providers you set on two places, instead of one in higher hierarchy... I don't know how I missed that before...

Comment: @miselking Interesting, thanks for answering (+1), I was scratching my head..lol

Comment: thnx u to @Vivek

Answer (score 1):

Create your observable as a class level variable in your service and assign values to it using `.next()`

Something like this (I haven't tested the code, just conceptually edited it):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from'; 
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {  BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class passVarHelper{

    currentIndex:BehaviorSubject<string>; 
    constructor(){
        this.currentIndex =  new BehaviorSubject<string>('Title');    
     }

    getIndex(): BehaviorSubject<string> {
        return this.currentIndex;
    }

    changeIndex(index:string){
        this.currentIndex.next(index);

    }

}
```

In the header component

```
index = getIndex();
```

In the header template (html), bind the index using async pipe

```
{{index | async}}
```

Comment: I change the currentIndex to <any> and i put .next but.. this.currentIndex.next is not a function

Comment: Make it of type Observable

Comment: making currentIndex Observable <any>  same :c

Comment: @user3562198 Let me know, I'll set this up and test and fix if this doesn't

Comment: The value arrives at the changeIndex function every time I select the menu, the console shows it to me. But, the index in the Header is not updated, only loads the first time "title"

Comment: Use `index = getIndex()` in the component and In you header html, you can directly bind `{{this.index | async}}`, updated the answer

Comment: if i put index = getIndex(); (say dont exist), so i put index = this._passVarHelper.getIndex(); but the same, not update

Comment: you are right, it should be     index = this._passVarHelper.getIndex(), can you post your html?

Comment: I put ur changues but dont works, (i put the html on the post) thank you for helping me

Comment: Are you using routes? or adding the app selectors in your app.html?

Comment: yes i use routes, the header and the menu, are on a dashboard component and this dashboard component ar on the app.html

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you should look into this section for component interaction on the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

You update the `currentIndex` variable, but I don't believe that triggers the Observable to update properly. The `currentIndex` should be an Observable variable that you can subscribe to and listen for changes in the variable.