# RxJS Observable life cycle in ngOnInit()

Tags: typescript

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // convert the `keyup` event into an observable stream
    Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .map((e: any) => e.target.value) // extract the value of the input
      .filter((text: string) => text.length > 1) // filter out if empty
      .debounceTime(250)                         // only once every 250ms
      .do(() => this.loading.emit(true))         // enable loading
      // search, discarding old events if new input comes in
      .map((query: string) => this.youtube.search(query))
      .switch()
      // act on the return of the search
      .subscribe(
        (results: SearchResult[]) => { // on sucesss
          this.loading.emit(false);
          this.results.emit(results);
        },
        (err: any) => { // on error
          console.log(err);
          this.loading.emit(false);
        },
        () => { // on completion
          this.loading.emit(false);
        }
      );
  }
```

Hi, as far as I know, ngOnInit() is invoked after the first detection change. My question is Observable.fromEvent creates an Observable stream. Does that mean the same stream is used when the 'keyup' event is triggered? If so, map() actually iterates every value in that stream?Eg. I type a then b, so there are 2 values in the stream? one is a another is a,b? That's why the switch method is used to return only the latest value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hi, as far as I know, ngOnInit() is invoked after the first detection change.

The first time input properties are received. This occurs from a change detection cycle in the parent component.

> My question is Observable.fromEvent creates an Observable stream. Does that mean the same stream is used when the 'keyup' event is triggered? If so, map() actually iterates every value in that stream?Eg. I type a then b, so there are 2 values in the stream? one is a another is a,b?

Yes, all `keyup` events are streamed to this single observable, one after the other.

> That's why the switch method is used to return only the latest value?

The `switch` is used to cancel any pending calls to `youtube.search(query)` in your sample code, once a new value is streamed.

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
```

I don't like this approach, as `this.el` might not be available at the time, or it can be re-created during the lifecycle of your component. With this approach you get events from the first element created, which may work then stop working all of sudden.

Instead, I'll bind the `keyup` event on the template and `next()` to a subject.

```html
<input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)">
```

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
...
keyupSubject = new Subject();
endEvent = new Subject();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.keyupSubject
        .map()
        .filter()
        .debounceTime()
        .takeUntil(this.endEvent) // automatically unsubscribe when component is destroyed
        .subscribe(() => {
            ...
        });        
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.endEvent.next();
}

onKeyup(event) {
    this.keyupSubject.next(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit() is called only one time when component is called.

ngOnChange() is called every time when angular detect the change.

Try with  ngOnChange() instead of ngOnInit()

Comment: subscribing in an `ngOnChanges()` would lead to multiple subscriptions

Comment: @Nikola Trajkovic hi, does that mean Observable is real-time? if I type a then b, does that mean there are two values in the stream? one is a and the other is a,b. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @PeterNguye it's not real time, right. Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952035/angular-observable-dont-show-me-values-in-real-time

Comment: @Peter observable is not an array that accumulates values, first you receive `a`, then you receive `b`. If you want `a,b` it's your job to accumulate the values

Comment: @André Werlang I don't want a,b. I'm trying to visualize the stream. When I first type ''a''. ''a'' is added to the stream and then I type b, the input text value is now "ab" so ab is added to the stream. Make no mistake, there's 2 values in the stream now. My question is :  does the map() function iterate from the first value when it does the transformation [(e: any) => e.target.value] to the end everytime a keyup event is triggered or observable is aware of which one is already is transformed and only look for the one that ain't?

Comment: @Peter on every keystroke, the first operator receives a new value, which is transformed/filtered and then delievered to the next operator in the chain, and so on, until it gets to the subscribe block. Observables don't keep track of who gets notified of new values down the chain.

Comment: @André Werlang Can you elaborate what do you mean by pending calls?

Comment: @Peter an observable that didn't complete; for instance a pending http request.